# ORB Feature Detector

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, homography, orb, pose-estimation

I'm working on a Marker less augmented reality project with Open CV. Currently i'm using ORB to detector features and augment 3D Objects. So far the models are augmented well but the augmentation is not smooth as expected. The Augmented 3D model is jittery.

What are the possible ways of refinement which will result in a smooth camera pose estimation between frames.

Thank You In Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Small jitters can be caused by the inherent pixel-level precision of most feature detectors. You could attempt to perform sub-pixel refinement on your detected points by calling [`cv::cornerSubPix()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=cornersubpix#cornersubpix).

One fairly common method of smoothing a pose is [double-exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Double_exponential_smoothing) filtering, which [claims](http://cs.brown.edu/~jjl/pubs/vr2003_laviola.pdf) high accuracy at low computational cost. The first link also mentions other methods which you may wish to implement.